# Determine Lebesgue integral of a function containing floor function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm practicing for the real-analysis exam and I've got stuck at this integral... Could you help me, please?
Determine: $$ \int_{[0,\infty)}\dfrac{1}{\lfloor{x+1}\rfloor\cdot\lfloor{x+2}\rfloor}d\lambda(x).$$
It is ok to split in two integrals and to obtain two natural logarithms?

Comment: Do you need an exact (closed form) value?

Comment: No, not really...

Comment: What are you looking for then? Determining convergence or something else?

Comment: Well, it wasn't specified in the exercise...But I think I have to check first whether it exists($<\infty$) and then to calculate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in[k, k+1)$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\lfloor{x}\rfloor=k$. Also, note that for any $l\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\lfloor{x+l}\rfloor = \lfloor{x}\rfloor + l$.
\begin{align}
\int_0^n \frac{1}{\lfloor{x+1}\rfloor\lfloor{x+2}\rfloor}\ dx
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{\lfloor{x+1}\rfloor\lfloor{x+2}\rfloor}\ dx\\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( \frac{1}{k+1}  - \frac{1}{k+2} \right)\\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1}  - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1}\\
&=
1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \text{.}
\end{align}

Comment: So the integral vanishes from the second row?

Comment: Yes, I have evaluated it.

Comment: Oh, I see, I understood now!

Comment: As n goes to infinity, the result will be just 1, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: I think in the second row it should be added $\lambda$ $([k+1,k+2))$, in order to be correct and complete...Of, course, this would be 1, but still

Comment: Also, I think we must specify that the interval $[k,k+1)$ is Lebesgue(it is Borel, because it is $(k,k+1)\cup{k}$), in order to be able to say that $f$ is measurable

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the value of the integrand changes only at integer values of $x$. For $x\in[0,1)$ it's $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}$. For $x\in[1,2)$, it's $\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}$. Can you figure out the value for $x\in [n, n+1)$? This means that you can express the integral as a sum (i.e., a series). I don't see a way to find the exact value of the series though.